# Show posts in a list separated by day

Tags: get-posts

I want to display posts on index page within a links-list, with only the titles, till now i did the job, but now i want to have space between titles and be separated by day.

Please check wimp.com and see how the titles are separated.

Right now my code is something like this

```
<?php query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-3');  
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


      <span class="date"><?php the_time('M j') ?></span>
-
<a class="title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to hold the previous post's date, and then add a `<br />` or something when it changes.

```
<?php
    $prev_date = ''; // initialize to empty string
    query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-3');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( strlen( $prev_date ) > 0 && get_the_time( 'M j' ) != $prev_date ): ?>
            <br /> <!-- or whatever you want to use to separate your date blocks -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <span class="date"><?php the_time('M j') ?></span> - 
        <a class="title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php $prev_date = get_the_time( 'M j' );
        ?>
<!-- continue on with The Loop -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: you are close, but something is not right because now the list is something like this:

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZdRnd21.gif

Comment: Whoops.  I've fixed the code sample; now the `<br />` will happen _before_ the post gets output, so if there needs to be a break, there will be.  Also added a check so that there won't be a spurious `<br />` at the top of the list.